# Group by two columns simultaneously in the way that grouping matches col1, col2 and col2,col1

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I have table "chat" with columns sender_id, recipient_id and message:

```
sender_id | recipient_id | message
-------------------------------------
     1    |      2       | Test 1
     2    |      1       | test test
     1    |      3       | more tests
     1    |      2       | aaaa
```

I want to group results on (sender_id, recipient_id) and in reverse (recipient_id, sender_id). Results should look like this:

```
sender_id | recipient_id
------------------------
     1    |      2
     1    |      3
```

It is because sender can be also recipient in another row and I don't want results like

```
sender_id | recipient_id
------------------------
     1    |      2
     2    |      1
```

This is SQL that works fine but have few flaws:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON sender_id+recipient_id, sender_id, recipient_id 
FROM chat 
WHERE (sender_id = 10 AND recipient_id = 10);
```

The flaws: 1. I can't use DISTINCT ON in my code. 2. It will group in one row (I'm not sure if it can really happen) something like this :

```
sender_id | recipient_id
------------------------
    10    |      5
     9    |      6
```

I don't have any clue how to solve this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` to get the lower ID first and the higher last (or vice versa, if you prefer).

With `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       least(sender_id, recipient_id) least_id,
       greatest(sender_id, recipient_id) greatest_id
       FROM chat;
```

Or with `GROUP BY`, if you actually want to aggregate something (whatever that may be, `max(message)`?):

```
SELECT least(sender_id, recipient_id) least_id,
       greatest(sender_id, recipient_id) greatest_id,
       ...
       FROM chat
            GROUP BY least(sender_id, recipient_id),
                     greatest(sender_id, recipient_id);
```

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you very much.